# Python, UTF-8 filesystem, iso-8859-1 files

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, filesystems, iso-8859-1

I have an application written in Python 2.7 that reads user's file from the hard-drive using os.walk.

The application requires a UTF-8 system locale (we check the env variables before it starts) because we handle files with Unicode characters (audio files with the artist name in it for example), and want to make sure we can save these files with the correct file name to the filesystem.

Some of our users have UTF-8 locales (therefore a UTF-8 fs), but still somehow manage to have ISO-8859-1 files stored on their drive. This causes problems when our code tries to os.walk() these directories as Python throws an exception when trying to decode this sequence of ISO-8859-1 bytes using UTF-8.

So my question is, how do I get python to ignore this file and move on to the next one instead of aborting the *entire* os.walk(). Should I just roll my own os.walk() function?

Edit: Until now we've been telling our users to use the convmv linux command to correct their filenames, however many users have various different types of encodings (8859-1, 8859-2, etc.), and using convmv requires the user to make an educated guess on what files have what encoding before they run convmv on each one individually.

Comment: There is a huge difference between filename encoding and terminal encoding. You cannot ever assume that the two correlate.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: We use the LANG env variable.

Comment: Could you use the `onerror` argument to `walk()`?  What exception is being thrown?

Comment: @sr2222: It will throw a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Comment: @MartinKonecny: Switching the LANG env variable does not switch the encoding used on the filesystem; os.listdir() works with the stored filenames on the system, which are not re-coded to suit the current `LANG` setting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Agreed but reading  "UTF-8" from sys.getfilesystemencoding doesn't magically make the files UTF-8 encoded either. But your method is defn more correct than mine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read [Unicode filenames](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#unicode-filenames), part of the Python Unicode how-to. Most importantly, filesystem encodings are not necessarily the same as the current LANG setting in the terminal.

Specifically, `os.walk` is built upon `os.listdir`, and will thus switch between unicode and 8-bit bytes depending on wether or not you give it a unicode path.

Pass it an 8-bit path instead, and your code will work properly, then decode from UTF-8 or ISO 8859-1 as needed.

Comment: This is the way to go.  Using byte strings (type `bytes` or `str` in Python 2.x, type `bytes` in 3.x) will also make the locale setting irrelevant.  Note that the whole problem is gone in Python 3.2, since filenames will be decoded with `errors="surrogateescape"`, which never fails.

Comment: The current filesystem encoding is determined by the environment variable `LC_CTYPE`, or `LANG` if the former is unset.  It can be queried by the Python function `sys.getfilesystemencoding()`.

Comment: "Then decode from UTF-8 or ISO 8859-1 as appropriate", how would I go about this? Try decoding from UTF-8 first, and if exception, try ISO-8859-1?

Comment: Decode from sys.getfilesystemencoding(), perhaps with errors="replace" or by catching UnicodeDecode errors and ignoring the filename in question.

Answer (score 0):

Use character encoding detection,  chardet modules for python work well for determining actual encoding with some confidence.  "as appropriate" -- You either know the encoding or you have to guess at it.  If with chardet you guess wrong, at least you tried.